# Helmholtz Problem in Circular Disk

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, graphics, parametric-functions

The following expression $$u_{nm}(r,\theta)=J_n(x_{nm}\frac{r}{a}) \begin{cases}
 \cos n \theta, & n=0,1,2 , m=1,2 \\ 
\sin n \theta, &
    \end{cases}$$ gives the solution for the Helmholtz problem. On the circular disc with center 0 and radius a. For a = 1,  the plot in 3-dimensional graphics of the solutions on Mathematica for $(n,m)=(2,2)$ and $(n,m)=(0,2)$ and then calculate the eigenfunction

$$k_{nm}= \frac{x_{nm}}{a}$$

```
a = 1;
m = 2; (*Set the value of m*)
x[m_] := N[BesselJ[2, m]]
(*calculate the eigenfunction k[m]*)
k[m_] := x[m]/a
TableForm [Table[{m, k[m]}, {m, 2, 2}], TableSpacing -> {3, 5}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"m", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(m\)]\)"}}]
```

My question is how could I define the function $u$ and create 3D graphics as the following picture shows

I was thinking to use this

```
u[r_, t_, m_] := (Cos[\[Omega][m]*t] + Sin[\[Omega][m]*t])*
  BesselJ[0, k[m]*r]
```

Is my consideration right?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be better to separate functions with $\sin (n\theta)$ and $\cos (n\theta)$ as follows

```
a = 1;
mmax = nmax = 2; (*Set the value of m, n *)
b[m_, n_] := BesselJZero[n, m];
(*calculate the eigenfunction k[m,n]*)
k[m_, n_] := N[b[m, n]/a];
uc[r_, t_, m_, n_] := (Cos[n t]) BesselJ[n, k[m, n]*r]; 
us[r_, t_, m_, n_] := (Sin[n t]) BesselJ[n, k[m, n]*r];
```

Visualization

```
rule = {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], t -> ArcTan[x, y]}; region = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[uc[r, t, m, n] /. rule], 
  Element[{x, y}, region], PlotLabel -> {n, m}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> "AuroraColors"], {n, 0, 
  nmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]

Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[us[r, t, m, n] /. rule], 
  Element[{x, y}, region], PlotLabel -> {n, m}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> "AuroraColors"], {n, 1, 
  nmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]
```

[image: Figure1]

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos You are welcome!