# Solving Helmholtz Equation in 2D for Circular Disk with DEigensystem, NDEigensystem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, parametric-functions

I would like to solve the Helmholtz equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions in two dimensions for a circular disk with a radius of 1.

$\Omega =$ some boundary e.g. a circle

$
\nabla^2 u(x,y) + k^2u(x,y) =0 \quad x,y \in \Omega \\
u(x,y) = 0 \quad x,y \in \partial\Omega
$

As discussed at [Helmholtz Problem in Circular Disk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283664/helmholtz-problem-in-circular-disk)

```
a = 1;
mmax = nmax = 2; (*Set the value of m,n*)
b[m_, n_] := BesselJZero[n, m];
(*calculate the eigenfunction k[m,n]*)
k[m_, n_] := N[b[m, n]/a];
uc[r_, t_, m_, n_] := (Cos[n t]) BesselJ[n, k[m, n]*r];
us[r_, t_, m_, n_] := (Sin[n t]) BesselJ[n, k[m, n]*r];
```

We created the eigenvalues of $k_{nm}$

```
data = Table[  N[b[m, n]/a], {m, 1, 5}, {n, 0, 2}]  ;
TableForm[ data , TableSpacing -> {3, 7}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center, 
 TableHeadings -> {{  1 , 2, 3, 4, 
    5}, {"\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"0\", \"x\"},\n\"BesselJ\"]\)", 
    "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"1\", \"x\"},\n\"BesselJ\"]\)", 
    "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"2\", \"x\"},\n\"BesselJ\"]\)"}}]
```

[image]
Visualization

```
rule = {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], t -> ArcTan[x, y]}; region = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[uc[r, t, m, n] /. rule], 
  Element[{x, y}, region], PlotLabel -> {n, m}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> "AuroraColors"], {n, 0, 
  nmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]

Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[us[r, t, m, n] /. rule], 
  Element[{x, y}, region], PlotLabel -> {n, m}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> "AuroraColors"], {n, 1, 
  nmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]
```

[image]

***Now we are trying to solve it with DEigensystem, NDEigensystem***

Compute the first 4 eigenfunctions for a circular membrane with the edges clamped:

- DEigensystem

```
Clear["Global`*"]
{vals, funs} = 
 DEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 4];
(*Calculate the eigenvalues*)
vals // N
(*isostatic eigenfunction curves*)
Table[Plot3D[
 funs[[i]] // N // Evaluate, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image]

- NDEigensystem

```
Clear["Global`*"]
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 4];
(*Calculate the eigenvalues*)
vals
(*isostatic eigenfunction curves*)
Table[Plot3D[funs[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image]

At which values of $k_{nm}$ of the relation
corresponding to the first 4 eigenvalues given by the command? Because I have found the eigenvalues but they don’t match these $k_{nm}$ of the above table. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are defined as solution  of equation $-\nabla^2 u(x, y)=\lambda_i u(x,y)$. In a case of $u=\cos (n \theta) J_n(k_{mn}r)$ we have

```
 -Laplacian[Cos[n \[Theta]] BesselJ[n, kmn r], {r, \[Theta]}, 
   "Polar"] // FullSimplify

Out[]= kmn^2 BesselJ[n, kmn r] Cos[n \[Theta]]
```

Therefore, $\lambda_{mn}=k_{mn}^2$. First eigenvalues

```
b[m_, n_] := BesselJZero[n, m];
k[m_, n_] := N[b[m, n]]; Table[{m, n, k[m, n]^2}, {m, 1, 3}, {n, 0, 2}]

{{{1, 0, 5.78319}, {1, 1, 14.682}, {1, 2, 26.3746}}, {{2, 0, 
   30.4713}, {2, 1, 49.2185}, {2, 2, 70.85}}, {{3, 0, 74.887}, {3, 1, 
   103.499}, {3, 2, 135.021}}}
```

Comment: So I can not find the corresponding values of the first right?

Comment: Oh i got it i have to compare it with $k_{nm}^2$